# How to handle Keydown event in Form level after All Child controls handled it?

Tags: c#, keypress, keydown

I have a form with two controls A  and B 
, A has a key-down event and i show a message box when 'S' is pressed on A control.
And i want to show another message when 'S' is pressed in any other control.

how can I do this ?

Simply what I want is :  I should be able to handle a Key-down event after all child controls.
and I should be able to know whether the Event is handle in a child control in Form-level Key-down.

I tried enabling Key-preview but when Key-preview is enabled Form-level event get's fired before child control events. I want child controls first, Then Form level one

I want form level Event to be fired after focused control's key down event is fired. 
and I want to check in Form-level event whether the event is handled in focused controls key-down event.

What methods can I use for this ?

Please enlighten me.

Comment: make sure you enabled the KeyPreview in the form properties

Comment: When Enabled KeyPreview, Form-level event get's fired before child control events. I want child controls first, Then Form level one

Comment: define a delegete handled in the form and let each control to fire this delegete after handling the key down, if you want a sample code, i am ready

Comment: Please post a sample.

Comment: Why do you need to do something like this? Have you considered any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following

here a sample code

1. Add new project call it EventSample
2. Add a UserControl call it AControl
3. Add a UserControl call it BControl
4. make the AControl BackColor Blue and BControl Red in order to
   distinguish from the form

//Form1 code

```
namespace EventSample
{
    public delegate void AfterChildEventHandler(Control control,Keys key);
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            aControl1.OnChildFireEvent += OnChildFireEvent;
            bControl1.OnChildFireEvent += OnChildFireEvent;
        }

        void OnChildFireEvent(Control control, Keys key)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Form fired event from " + control.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
}
```

//AControl code

```
namespace EventSample
{
    public partial class AControl : UserControl
    {
        public event AfterChildEventHandler OnChildFireEvent;
        public AControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A Control fired Key down");
            if (OnChildFireEvent != null)
                OnChildFireEvent(this, e.KeyCode);
        }
    }
}
```

//BControl code

```
public partial class BControl : UserControl
    {
        public event AfterChildEventHandler OnChildFireEvent;
        public BControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("B Control fired Key down");
            if (OnChildFireEvent != null)
                OnChildFireEvent(this, e.KeyCode);
        }
    }
```

**EDITED**

another solution you can make it with less code

1. define a static event
2. handle this event inside the form
3. let each control to invoke this event

   namespace EventSample
   {

   ```
   public delegate void AfterChildEventHandler(Control control, Keys key);

   public class GlobalEvent
   {
       public static event AfterChildEventHandler OnChildEventFire;

       public static void Invoke(Control control, Keys key)
       {
           if (OnChildEventFire != null)
               OnChildEventFire(control, key);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

changes in the A Control

```
namespace EventSample
{
    public partial class AControl : UserControl
    {
        public AControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A Control fired Key down");
            GlobalEvent.Invoke(this, e.KeyCode);
        }
    }
}
```

changes in the B Control

```
namespace EventSample
{
    public partial class BControl : UserControl
    {
        public BControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("B Control fired Key down");
            GlobalEvent.Invoke(this, e.KeyCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Build the sample and run and try to press any key on A or B then you will find that A will fire then the form

hope it will help you

Comment: May be there is Something we can do with overiding processKeypreview , ProcessKeyCmd  methods ,   As this example will so hard to imlement when we have hundreds of Derived forms.

Comment: Something which is easier than this. I am looking for more mature answer.

Comment: make this event as singleton, and let the controls to call it( without defining it inside the control), and let the form to handle this event only

Comment: i will edit the code to show you, this solution in my opinion will be the best since your event will be visible on the level of your project

Comment: @RealProgrammer check my code after EDITED word please, this will not make headache to define each time the event of the child control, just the child will call the event and form will handle automatically

Comment: Marked this as answer and gave you an upvote, That's  what i can do for you